# Create xsl key by "joining" elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<t>
  <rendition xml:id="b">color: blue</rendition>
  <rendition xml:id="r">color: red</rendition>

  <tagUsage gi="p" render="b" />
  <tagUsage gi="emph" render="r" />
</t>
```

How would I create an XSL 1.0 key into rendition elements based on @gi in the tagUsage element, joining rendition/@xml:id to tagUsage/@render? Something like

```
<xsl:key name="rendition-by-tagName" 
         match="rendition" 
         use="//tagUsage[@xml:id of rendition = @render of tagUsage]/@gi" />
```

so that given "p", the key would return the blue `rendition`; given "emph", the key would return the red `rendition`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
 <xsl:key name="kRendByUsageGi" match="rendition"
  use="../tagUsage[@render=current()/@xml:id]/@gi"/>
```

**Here is a complete verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRendByUsageGi" match="rendition"
  use="../tagUsage[@render=current()/@xml:id]/@gi"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRendByUsageGi', 'p')/text()"/>
========
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRendByUsageGi', 'emph')/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<t>
  <rendition xml:id="b">color: blue</rendition>
  <rendition xml:id="r">color: red</rendition>

  <tagUsage gi="p" render="b" />
  <tagUsage gi="emph" render="r" />
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
color: blue
========
  color: red
```

Comment: I think there is a bug in whatever xslt processor Google Chrome uses. This works fine in Xalan and Saxon in oXygen and in client-side processing in Firefox and Internet Explorer but not in Chrome: current() is not referencing the matched element. Yuk.

Comment: @JPM, Yes, I have heard also about a "security" feature of Chrome that severely limits client-side XSLT processing. Given such less than good XSLT implementation, one would seriously consider Saxon CE, which, I believe,  behaves as a normal XSLT 2.0 processor under all five major browsers.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this one is a bug. I've discovered that current() in @use fails in xsltproc and Safari also. Chrome, Safari and xsltproc have, I believe, common xslt code.

Comment: @JPM, I believe so, too. The syntax of the `xsl:key` instruction doesn't restrict what can be specified in the `use` attribute -- *any* XPath expression may be specified, including any functions defined in the XPAth evaluation context (meaning any XSLT functions): http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key

Comment: I guess I'll just define two keys and nest them. That won't be as fast but should be fine.

Comment: @JPM, Yes, that should work. An additional call to `key()` isn't expensive at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following, which uses a second key(), works with xsltproc, so, if that's your target processor, this should help.  It doesn't work with Saxon, though.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name='kTagUsage' match='tagUsage' use='@render'/>
  <xsl:key name="kRendByUsageGi" match="rendition"
    use="key('kTagUsage', @xml:id)/@gi"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRendByUsageGi', 'p')/text()"/>
    ========
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('kRendByUsageGi', 'emph')/text()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```